# A diff which compares changes within lines for Mac OS X

Tags: compare, diff

I'm looking for software that would let me apply changes within lines – not necessarily automaticall – rather than the whole line. I read that wdiff can do this, however there is no Mac OS X version.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Homebrew, you can use:

```
brew install wdiff
```

If you want to see the differences in color, try:

```
brew install colordiff
```

Then you can do:

```
wdiff file1.txt file2.txt | colordiff
```

or

```
wdiff file1.txt file2.txt | colordiff | less -R
```

Answer (score 2):

There is (now) a version of wdiff available for Mac OS X.  Just install MacPorts and run "sudo port install wdiff".

-Scott

Answer (score 0):

There are probably lots of options for this. The first I came across with a quick Google search is [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I've tried KDiff3, it doesn't let you *apply* changes within a line, just shows it

Answer (score 0):

I use [DeltaWalker](http://www.deltopia.com/compare-merge-sync/macosx/) but use [AlternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/software/deltawalker/?platform=mac) to see other options

Comment: DeltaWalker is a great tool, but I wouldn't recommend purchasing it, as the "lifetime" licence I purchased 2 years ago is now expired and Deltopia has remained silent about my mails on the subject. So it was actually a 20$/year licence (really expensive considering the product).